# Difference between interval() and repeatWhen() for polling from an Observable in intervals

Tags: rx-java

Is there any difference between:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable
        .interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<String> call(Long aLong) {
                return Observable.just("MyString");
            }
        })
```

and:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("MyString")
        .repeatWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Void>, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Void> completed) {
                return completed.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        })
```

The second is cleaner but in practical terms and considering backpressure, will these two solutions behave the same way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on your source observable (which in this case is `just("MyString")`) there could be a couple differences:

1. `interval()` will run every second (if possible), whereas `repeatWhen()` will always `delay()` by 1 second. For `just()` this doesn't matter, but if your source takes a while to run (e.g. 500ms) then you will see a difference in timing: `interval()` will resubscribe every 1,000ms, but `repeatWhen(delay())` will run every 1,500ms (500ms output + 1,000ms delay).

   If your source takes *longer* than a second, then there will be no pause between each resubscription with `interval()`, since it'll just wait until the previous `flatMap()` is done before executing another one!
2. If you use a `Scheduler` within the `flatMap()` then you can achieve some parallelization that's not possible with `repeatWhen()`. Again, this doesn't really matter for `just()`, but it would for a long-running `Observable`. For more on that, check out [this great article](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html).

I'm not confident these are *all* the differences between the two, someone who is more familiar with RxJava's internals could probably point more out.